# Change image by id

Tags: javascript, html, image, random, numbers

I'm totally new in JavaScript.
I need to change image randomly on click.
Here is my code. What's wrong?
I'm trying to make a dice game where you roll a dice and a image value pops.
I only get the number change on screen when i click on image, but the image only changes from 1.jpg to 6.jpg and thats all.

**HTML**

```
<img id="myImage" onclick="changeImage()" src="1.jpg" width="100" height="100">
<p id="pl" ></p>
```

**JS**

```
function myFunction() {
    var x = Math.floor((Math.random() * 6) + 1);
    document.getElementById("pl").innerHTML = x;
}

function changeImage() {
    var image = document.getElementById('myImage');
    var pl;

    pl = myFunction();
    if (pl == 1) {
        image.src = "1.jpg";
    } else if (pl == 2) {
        image.src = "2.jpg";
    } else if (pl == 3) {
        image.src = "3.jpg";
    } else if (pl == 4) {
        image.src = "4.jpg";
    } else if (pl == 5) {
        image.src = "5.jpg";
    } else {
        image.src = "6.jpg";
    }
}
```

Comment: what happens when you run this?

Comment: I only get the number change on screen when i click on image, but the image only changes from 1.jpg to 6.jpg and thats all.

Comment: Return x in your function

Answer (score 0, accepted):

`myFunction` isn't returning `x`, but you're setting `p1 = myFunction()`, so `p1` will equal `undefined`. Add a return statement to fix:

```
function myFunction() {
    var x = Math.floor((Math.random() * 6) + 1);
    document.getElementById("pl").innerHTML = x;
    return x;
}
```

---

Here are some other pointers:

- You don't need multiple `<script>` tags. All of your code can go in one.
- `<script>` tags should be inside of your `<head>` or `<body>`. It's invalid markup for `<html>` to contain anything other than `<head>` or `<body>`<sup>[MDN](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/HTML/Element/html)</sup> (though it may still work).
- Instead of a huge `if` statement, try using a `switch`.
- Even better, simply set `image.src = p1 + ".jpg"`. It's much easier to read!
- You mispelt yor openning `<hml>` tagg.

Otherwise, it looks like you're shaping up to be a great JavaScript developer! Keep at it! :)

Comment: @LakyJ if this or *any answer* has solved your question please consider [accepting it](http://meta.stackexchange.com/q/5234/179419) by clicking the check-mark. This indicates to the wider community that you've found a solution and gives some reputation to both the answerer and yourself. There is no obligation to do this. Happy Coding!

Answer (score 0):

### See this [fiddle](https://jsfiddle.net/ouctt4qp/1/)

change your `myFunction()` as below

```
function myFunction() {
  var x = Math.floor((Math.random() * 6) + 1);
  document.getElementById("pl").innerHTML = x;
  return x;
}
```

You were not returning the value of `myFunction()` to `pl` which was causing the `6.jpg` to be shown always (since it was entering the else block always).

Answer (score 0):

you set pl equal to myFunction();. what you really want is to set pl equal to document.getElementById("pl").innerHTML. Also, make sure that myFunction() fires before changeImage(). Here it is in a JS fiddle working https://jsfiddle.net/hdz7x23p/ Inspect the broken image icon to see the source changed.

```
var pl = document.getElementById("pl").innerHTML;
```

Answer (score 0):

You need to do two small corrections in your code

1. **Return the value**

return document.getElementById("pl").innerHTML = x;

2. **Use double quotes**

var image = document.getElementById("myImage");

Answer (score 0):

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
<body>


<img id="myImage"   src="1.jpg" onclick="changeImage()" width="100" height="100">

<p id="pl" ></p>

</body>

<script>
function myFunction() {
    var x = Math.floor((Math.random() * 6) + 1);
    return document.getElementById("pl").innerHTML = x;


}

</script>

<script>
function changeImage() {
    var image = document.getElementById("myImage");
    var pl;


    pl = myFunction();
    if (pl == 1) {
        image.src = "1.jpg";
    } else if (pl == 2) {
        image.src = "2.jpg";
    } else if (pl == 3) {
        image.src = "3.jpg";
    } else if (pl == 4) {
        image.src = "4.jpg";
    } else if (pl == 5) {
        image.src = "5.jpg";
    } else {
        image.src = "6.jpg";
        }
}
</script>


</html>
```